# d3 arc tween won't work inside a function call

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a pie chart using [this blocks](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/32bd93b1cc0fbccc9bf9) example for growing the pie slice on mouseover. In addition to the tween, I also want to have the pie slices change colors and have a tooltip, so I want to have another function called that can work with d and i.

The problem is that although the arcTween function works as written on the mouseover, it will not work if it is wrapped in another function -- which I want to do so that I can access the index for tooltip.

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working? I have tried many ways of returning the function with different variables and can't get it working.

Full code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    path {
      stroke: #333;
      fill-opacity: 90%;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      transition: fill 250ms linear;
      transition-delay: 150ms;
    }


    path:hover {


    stroke: #000;
    fill-opacity: 100%;

      transition-delay: 0;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var data = [44, 16, 9, 8,8,8,4,3];

    function findColor(index){

      var colors = [
        "#cb5b49",
        "#8bbbd3",
        "#1f61a3",
        "#c7dae4",
        "#f0d0bd",
        "#e89d7b",
        "#a91729",
        "#408cb9"];

        return colors[index];

      }


    var width = 960,
        height = 500;

    var outerRadius = height / 2 - 20,
      cornerRadius = 10;

    var pie = d3.layout.pie();

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .padRadius(outerRadius);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("path")
        .each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill",function(d, i){return findColor(i)})
        .on("mouseover", arcTween(outerRadius + 20, 0)) //THIS WORKS
          //THE BELOW DOES NOT WORK FOR SOME REASON
         // .on("mouseover", function(d,i){console.log(i); return arcTween(outerRadius + 20, 0);})
        .on("mouseout", arcTween(outerRadius - 20, 150));


    function arcTween(outerRadius, delay) {
      return function() {
        d3.select(this).transition().delay(delay).attrTween("d", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
          return function(t) { d.outerRadius = i(t); return arc(d); };
        });
      };
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @LarsKotthoff, you need this for a fix: jsfiddle.net/vndrw57a

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("path")
    .each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill",function(d, i){return findColor(i)})
    .on("mouseover", function(){ arcTween(outerRadius + 20, 0, this)(); })
    .on("mouseout", arcTween(outerRadius - 20, 150));


function arcTween(outerRadius, delay, that) {
  return function() {
    var el = (that !== undefined ? that : this);
    d3.select(el).transition().delay(delay).attrTween("d", function(d) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
      return function(t) { d.outerRadius = i(t); return arc(d); };
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
function(d,i){console.log(i); return arcTween(outerRadius + 20, 0);})
```

returns a function (the return value of `arcTween`), it doesn't execute the function. You can execute the function by adding `()`

```
function(d,i){console.log(i); arcTween(outerRadius + 20, 0)();})
```

Comment: I have tried it like that and unfortunately, it also doesn't work.

Comment: It should be `arcTween(outerRadius + 20, 0)(d, i);`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff   .on("mouseover", function(d, i){console.log(i); arcTween(outerRadius + 20, 0)(d,i);}) prints i but doesn't execute the tween and gives the following error: Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh you also need a `return` in front of that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff with .on("mouseover", function(d, i){console.log(i); arcTween(outerRadius + 20, 0); return(d,i);}) there is no error, it does print the console log but it still doesn't do the tween.

Comment: Ah I see, I was wrong -- the problem is the `this`. Fixing this is a bit ugly unfortunately: http://jsfiddle.net/vndrw57a/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks! Am posting the answer below in case others have the same question.